# Python HTML Parsing with BS4

Tags: python, html, parsing, beautifulsoup

I'm having the problem of trying to parse through HTML using Python & Beautiful Soup and I'm encountering the problem of which I want to parse for a very specific piece of data. This is the kind of code I'm encountering:

```
<div class="big_div">
   <div class="smaller div">
      <div class="other div">
         <div class="this">A</div>
         <div class="that">2213</div>
      <div class="other div">
         <div class="this">B</div>
         <div class="that">215</div>
      <div class="other div">
         <div class="this">C</div>
         <div class="that">253</div>
```

There is a series of repeat HTML as you can see with only the values being different, my problem is locating a specific value. **I want to locate the 253 in the last div.** I would appreciate any help as this is a recurring problem in parsing through HTML.

Thank you in advance!

So far I've tried to parse for it but because the names are the same I have no idea how to navigate through it. I've tried using the for loop too but made little to no progress at all.

Comment: Firstly read docs or some sources about that if you have no idea;

Comment: Sorry I'm new at python I wasn't sure there was docs for this. Thankyou!

Comment: I was curious since there is an easier method of doing this is it possible to parse through javascript because I have a recurring problem where when I type something along the lines of        site = soup.find('script' type_='text/javascript')

Answer (score 0):

You can use string attribute as argument in find. [BS docs for string attr.](https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/index.html?highlight=select#the-string-argument)

```
"""Suppose html is the object holding html code of your web page that you want to scrape
and req_text is some text that you want to find"""
soup = BeautifulSoup(html, 'lxml')
req_div = soup.find('div', string=req_text)
```

`req_div` will contain the div element which you want.

Answer (score 0):

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from concurrent.futures import ThreadPoolExecutor

themes = ['Одежда', 'Животные', 'Политика', 'IT']

def get_links(theme):
    page = requests.get(f'https://habr.com/ru/search/page1/?q={theme}&target_type=posts&order=relevance').text
    page_soup = BeautifulSoup(page, 'html.parser')
    count_pages = int(page_soup.find_all('div', 'tm-pagination__page-group')[-1].text.split()[0])
    hrefs = []
    for i in range(1, count_pages + 1):
        print(i)
        page = requests.get(f'https://habr.com/ru/search/page{i}/?q={theme}&target_type=posts&order=relevance').text
        page_s = BeautifulSoup(page, 'html.parser')
        links = page_s.find_all('article', 'tm-articles-list__item')
        hrefs.extend([f'https://habr.com/ru/news/{link["id"]}/' for link in links])
    return hrefs

def get_text(href):
    print(href)
    try:
        pagex = requests.get(href).text
        page_su = BeautifulSoup(pagex, 'html.parser')
        text = page_su.find_all("div", "article-formatted-body article-formatted-body article-formatted-body_version-1")[0].text
        return text
    except:
        return ''


all_texts = []
for theme in themes:
    print(f'Сбор ссылок по теме {theme} начат')
    hrefs = get_links(theme)
    print(f'Сбор ссылок по теме {theme} закончен')
    texts = [''] * 1000
    with ThreadPoolExecutor() as executor:
        results = list(executor.map(get_text, hrefs))
    all_texts += results
    print('Сбор текстов по ссылкам окончен')
```

Comment: How this is answering the question? Please add some explanation for your code rather than posting code only. Additional explanation will be more helpful.